# open FW ports for splunk

Tags: splunk

I need to open up some firewall ports so that the splunk agent on our servers can communicate with Splunk.

Our splunk setup is split up into the following services and ports:

```
 Splunk Web/API  443, 8009, 8090, 8089
 Splunk Cluster Master 8000, 8001
 Splunk Deployment Server   8000, 8002, 8089
 Splunk Intermediate Forwarder TCP:6514:6514,6515,6516
                               TCP:514:10514,10515,10516
                               TCP:9997:9997,9998,9999
                               TCP:11514:11514
                               TCP:11515:11515
                               TCP:11516:11516
                               TCP:11517:11517
```

What ports do I need to open so that the splunk agent can ship logs to the splunk server? So that all logs from that server that you specify in the config will show up in the splunk interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the port for the UF (Universal Forwarder) agent in Splunk solution (settings > forward and receiving menu) and check which port is defined there. by default use the 9997 port. you should allow this port for your agent

Answer (score 2):

**Baseline**: Forwarder needs to connect to `indexer:9997` and `deployment-server:8089`. These are roles. `indexer` can also be a "fat forwarder".

Btw:

1. You use a strange format for showing open ports, please check and leave out ports that aren't strictly used for the service's main purpose. (i.e. what is the deployment server receiving on port 8002?)
2. depending on 1. I can detail this answer some more

Answer (score 0):

all administrative functions (deployment, licensing, etc..) happen on port 8089.
The default data ingest port for Splunk is usually 9997, soooo...

1. if you want to configure the forwarder from the deployment server, make sure it can reach your deployment server on port 8089
2. If you want your configured forwarder to send data to the indexers, then open port 9997 between your forwarder and ALL of your indexers. I say all because i'm unsure if you have a cluster or not.

This is to get data in. If your replicating data, or have a search head cluster, or cluster master, things get different.

Port 8000 is used to access Splunk web, and port 8090 is usually default for the HTTP inputs on any Splunk CORE device.

after that, the ports look custom save 514 (syslog).  You would likely need to dig into your deployment and figure out what is coming in on those ports.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from what you have asked, I think port 9997 will be the port that needs to be allowed FROM splunk agents TO Splunk server

Answer (score 0):

Check out this visual representation of the Splunk component communication, courtesy of *Aplura*
https://www.aplura.com/assets/images/splunk_common_ports.png